# Share file to other applications for editing and save back in same location

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I have created a file(text file) in external cache directory `context.getExternalCacheDir()`

and shared the file to other applications for editing using the file provider and granted the write access.

```
intent.setFlags( FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION );
```

File is opening in the editor application and when I try to modify the content and save, it asks for the path to save. I want the file saved back in same location from where it was opened instead of prompting the user to select a location.

Comment: Ask the developer of the editor application.

Comment: So is this should be handled by the editor app?

Comment: It has write access to the content. It should be able to save there. It could be that the editor sees a `content` scheme and assumes that it cannot write there. Only the developer of the editor app can tell you what the editor app is doing.